# Null is not null?

Tags: c#, .net

Following code

```
        if (_LastMouseClickArea != null)
        {
            if (_LastMouseClickArea.GridItem == GridItem.DataCell)
            {...
```

fails because `_LastMouseClickArea` is null. I know it sounds silly, so I came here.

From Immediate Window:

```
_LastMouseClickArea != null
true
_LastMouseClickArea 
null
_LastMouseClickArea == null
false
_LastMouseClickArea.GetType()
'((object)(this._LastMouseClickArea))' is null
```

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question, but this is not the appropriate format.

Comment: Is there an open question somewhere here?

Comment: Remove the resolution from the question and post it as a more detailed answer.

Comment: You must be doing something else because `null == null` always yields a positive result for me.

Comment: @ChrisF I'll do as you recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolution:** Before submitting, I remembered to do some Rubber duck debugging. That led me to check how `==` is implemented, and, sure enough, there was some strange P/Invoke call for which `null != null` equals `true`.

So here it is, for future reference, if anyone encounters the same issue.

Comment: what was the P/Invoke call being executed?

Comment: @Spence something along the lines of `return CPINVOKE.GridArea_eq(CValueType.getCPtr(lhs), CValueType.getCPtr(rhs));`

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you have a race condition?  As in it's not null when you check, but then a thread sets it null before you are able to use it.

Comment: Is it possible somewhere in your codebase the operator == has been overridden?  It shouldn't be P/Invoking to do this call.  I have seen a pattern where you check Nan != Nan as this is a hardware accelerated call, but not for null references.  Null == null will return true in the default C# implementation.